# Where to buy non scam bitcoin with ICBC credit card?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I've tried several bitcoin sites which accept credit cards, but they didn't accept my bank's credit card (miicard require bank verification and ICBC is not on the list), so where can I buy bitcoin from a reliable exchange with an ICBC credit card?

Answer (score 2):

You are likely to have trouble finding a place to buy Bitcoin with a credit card. A credit card transaction can often be charged back, in which case the seller has no way to recover the  bitcoins. Honest sellers may not want to take this risk, meaning they are probably far outnumbered by scammers.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, due to the fear of you asking to be charged back, almost no seller is going to accept a credit/debit card in exchange for Bitcoins.

If your bank allows you to get cash as a kind of "credit card transaction" (some do!) you might want to try that option and then pay in cash - you can **always** find people gladly selling in exchange for cash, and you can still pay monthly (in fiat) to your bank:

https://localbitcoins.com/